# Why mailgun and not a simple SMTP server

Tags: smtp, mailgun, spam

When I do mass mailings, many of the recipients complain that my mails end up in their spam folder. How can I prevent this. Should I perhaps use Mailgun? Currently I send the mails via a simple SMTP server.